# Auto-Refresh Field that has been Calculated with Python in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: field-calculator, attribute-table, arcgis-pro, python-parser, refresh

Is there a way to get a calculated field to auto-refresh?

For example, I have an expiration date field with dates filled in. I have another field that I will use to show the number of days left till the expiration date. When I update the expiration date to a new date, is there a way to get the calculated fields to auto-refresh with out having to rerun the Field Calculation - GeoProcessing Tool python script?

Below I've provided a screen shot of my attribute table.

[image]

Comment: im not sure about ArcGIS Pro but if you use ArcDesktop you can use "Attribute Assistant" to create an expression that will automatically calculate a field based on other fields.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that. Is Attribute Assistant a Geoprocessing Tool in ArcDesktop?

Comment: It is an add-on for ArcGIS Desktop.  Download it here - https://solutions.arcgis.com/shared/help/attribute-assistant/ and then read the help file.  It is quite useful for populating a field based on a custom expression or populating a field based on a spatial intersect.  I use it quite a bit myself.

Comment: It doesn't look like anything is available like this in ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: QGIS automatically refreshes a calculated field after you update a date field without having to add a product on the software. Something so simple you would think would be available for ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Well attribute assistant is actually free, but you are correct i dont think it will work with ArcPRO.

Comment: Look into "Attribute Rules" for ArcGIS Pro

Comment: [Attribute Rules](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/geodatabases/overview/an-overview-of-attribute-rules.htm) - this is the ArcGIS Pro release of the Attribute Assistant.  I don't think it's fully implemented all of the AA yet, but I think what you want may be included.